# Why is my web application generating a 1064 (42000) error when trying to POST an INSERT query?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-wtforms, user-registration

I'm trying to create a user registration page using Flask, MySQL and HTML forms. I'm running into this error when I try to post data from the form to the database. Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong with the SQL?

The full error received is:

1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

My connection function is:

```
import mysql.connector
from flask import *

def connection():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", db="user_login",user="root",
                                password="password")
    c = conn.cursor()
    return c, conn
```

This is imported in the **init**.py file and called below:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    firstName = StringField('First Name', [validators.Length(min = 3, max = 25)])
    lastName = StringField('Surname', [validators.Length(min = 3, max = 25)])
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min = 4, max = 25)])
    email = StringField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min = 6, max = 50)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.required(),
                                      validators.EqualTo('confirm', message = 'Passwords must match')])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')


@app.route('/register/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    try:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.form)

        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
            firstName = form.firstName.data
            lastName = form.lastName.data
            username = form.username.data
            email = form.email.data
            password = form.password.data
            is_admin = 0
            c, conn = connection()


            x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s",(username))

            if int(x) > 0:
                flash("That username is already taken, please choose another")
                return render_template('register.html', form = form)
            else:
                c.execute("""
                        INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, username, email, password, is_admin)
                        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                        """,(firstName, lastName, username, email, password, is_admin))
                conn.commit()
                flash("Thanks for registering!")
                c.close()
                conn.close()
                gc.collect()
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['username'] = username
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return render_template('register.html', form = form)

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is the `SELECT`, not the `INSERT`. You are passing `(username)` as a parameter -- this is *not* a tuple. You need to use a trailing comma:

```
x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", (username,))
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed this and started receiving an error saying "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'". 

I believe it was because x was returning a list. I edited this to say "if len(x) > 0:" and it is posting to my database. 

Thanks again.